# AFNetworking 2.0: NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I tried to *GET* html from Apple homepage.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager
= [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://www.apple.com/jp" parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"HTML: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This failed with error message as below:

```
2014-02-07 14:54:22.922 Tests[1833:70b] Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x8a32650 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.apple.com/jp/, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xea2e1a0> { URL: http://www.apple.com/jp/ } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=237";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 4402;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 07 Feb 2014 05:52:51 GMT";
    Expires = "Fri, 07 Feb 2014 05:56:48 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    Via = "1.0 proxy1.screen.co.jp (squid)";
    "X-Cache" = "MISS from proxy1.screen.co.jp";
    "X-Cache-Lookup" = "HIT from proxy1.screen.co.jp:8080";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}
```

I found the message `Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html` so I understand I have to let text/html acceptable. Then, I added the line: `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];`.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager 
= [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes
= [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]; // ###### ADDED LINE ######
[manager GET:@"http://www.apple.com/jp" parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"HTML: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But this failed, too.

```
2014-02-07 14:55:48.927 Tests[1873:70b]
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"
(JSON text did not start with
array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
UserInfo=0xfa7b870 {NSDebugDescription=
JSON text did not start with
array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` defaults to a `responseSerializer` of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. By changing `acceptableContentTypes`, you are changing which content types will be accepted, but you're not changing the fact that `AFJSONResponseSerializer` will still look for JSON in the response.

You might want to just set the `responseSerializer` to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`, so that it will no longer try to parse the JSON (and will automatically accept `text/html`):

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: I also have to chage the line:`NSLog(@"HTML: %@", [responseObject stringValue]);`

Comment: I found more simple way: `NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.co.jp/"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];` I don't have to use AFNetworking...

Comment: @weed That's fine, if that works for you, but note that that's a synchronous call, which you should never do from the main thread. If you dispatch this code to a background queue, then that's ok (but still loses some benefits of AFNetworking or a delegate-based NSURLConnection, e.g. cancelable requests). Bottom line, don't use AFNetworking if you don't want, but I hate to see you throw the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Rob. I'm going to try AFNetworking.

Comment: I THINK YOU NAILED IT BRO! Thank you so Much! Hey so Do I Have to change the responseSerializer to a previous Value?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with wget, and ending with "jp" gave a 301 redirect.

Try ending it with "jp/".